# Merging macbook* tags on SU

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

On Superuser, there are two tags for the same subject :

- ***macbookpro***, with 122 hits
- ***macbook-pro***, with 3 hits

That would be nice is someone could merge these two tags to ***macbook-pro*** (with a hyphen) I suggest, because you can already find the tag ***macbook-air*** (with a hyphen) and because you write *MacBook Pro* in two separate words.

By the way the tag ***macbook-unibody*** is only used 4 times, 2 times unnecessarily.
Moreover, this tag is ambiguous, because there are *MacBook unibody* and *MacBook Pro unibody*.

I don't know if we should delete this tag or merge it with macbook or macbook-pro, but at the moment it's not useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done.

I agree with you that is should be **macbook-pro** as it follows the same convention as **macbook-air** and so forth.

For the unibody ones, I went through and modified them one by one as they each dealt with different issues and there was not many of them. One of them was specific to unibody models and HDD upgrades.